CloudWatch Error: Rule JobFailureRule should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found
I have used below logic in CDK script for setting up Cloudwatch alarm and send SNS notification when there is failure in my glue job but when i tried to do npx synth then it throws error : Error: Rule at '{DVRD replication} JobFailureRule' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found.
export interface InfraStackProps extends VpcStackProps {
  stageName?: string;
}

export class InfraStack extends VpcStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: InfraStackProps ) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    // jobName. This is our AWS Glue script to monitor
    const jobFailedRule = new Rule(scope, '{DVRD replication} JobFailureRule', {
      eventPattern: {
        source: ['aws.glue'],
        detailType: ['Glue Job State Change'],
        detail: {
          state: ['FAILED', 'TIMEOUT', 'ERROR'],
          jobName: ['DVRD replication'],
        },
      },
    })
    
    //cloudwatch metric
    const numFailedJobsMetric = new cloudwatch.Metric({
      namespace: 'AWS/Events',
      metricName: 'TriggeredRules',
      statistic: 'Sum',
      dimensionsMap: {
        RuleName: jobFailedRule.ruleName,
      },
    })
    
    //cloudwatch alarm
    const numFailedJobsAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(scope, '{DVRD replication} numFailedJobsAlarm', {
      metric: numFailedJobsMetric,
      threshold: 1,
      evaluationPeriods: 1,
    });
    
    
    // Adding an SNS action and an email registration 
    const notificationsTopic = new Topic(this, 'Topic'); 
    numFailedJobsAlarm.addAlarmAction(new SnsAction(notificationsTopic));
    notificationsTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription('trst@gmail.com'));


And where is scope defined and what is its value?

i have updated question and added where i have defined stack at the top of cdk code..and then i have added logic to create glue job and then at then at the end i have added logic for cloudwatch as mentioned in the question..hope that helps

You are passing scope (that was passed when the Stack was instantiated) instead of this (the Stack itself) as the scope when creating your constructs. This is incorrect - when creating constructs in a stack, you should pass the stack itself (passing this is the correct option in 99% of cases).
I'm guessing scope is actually a CDK App.
Change scope to this and it should work.

thanks its working now. Just another question not related to maybe my current question. I have found this logic for cloudwatch in one article and used as it is. Just wanted to know will this logic sends notification when my glue job failed or there is not data ?
